# Python List data received from external device RFSniffer

Tags: python

I have a program in python that receives data from an external device.

```
(...)
while True:
    s = check_output(["./RFSniffer"])
(...)
```

How can I save my data into a list or array while it is receving data?

Comment: Using the `append` function? Is there something more complicated to this question I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

list [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) will do the work for you

```
(...)
while True:
    s.append(check_output(["./RFSniffer"]))
(...)
```